# regular expression: remove consecutive repeated characters at least 2 times as well as those after it in a string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector with different strings like this:

```
s <- c("mir123mm8", "qwe98wwww98", "123m3tqppppw23!")
```

and

```
> s
[1] "mir123mm8"       "qwe98wwww98"     "123m3tqppppw23!"
```

I would like to have the answer like this:

```
> c("mir123", "qwe98", "123m3tq")
[1] "mir123"  "qwe98"   "123m3tq"
```

That means that if a string has at least 2 consecutive repeated characters, then them and after them should be removed.

What is the better way to do it using regular expression in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use back reference in the pattern to match repeated characters:

```
sub("(.*?)(.)\\2.*", "\\1", s)
# [1] "mir123"  "qwe98"   "123m3tq"
```

The pattern matches when the second captured group which is a single character repeats directly after it. Make the first capture group ungreedy by *?* so that whenever the pattern matches, the first captured group is returned.

Comment: Thanks @Psidom.  It is very helpful.